# Obtener un número aleatorio dentro de un rango con Javascript

Tags: javascript

Quiero obtener un número *x* entre *a* y *z* usando una función.

La función la he formulado con 2 parámetros para comprender mejor que serán *min* y *max*,
haciendo referencia *min* = número mínimo y max = número máximo.

¿Qué operación debo hacer para que me devuelva un número aleatorio entre un rango u otro?

```js
function randomRangeNumber(min, max){
       return undefined; //puse undefined por poner algo pero deberia devolver el num aleatorio estre min y max
  }

console.log(randomRangeNumber(1, 5)) // debe devolver un numero entre el 1 y el 5
console.log(randomRangeNumber(6, 9)) // debe devolver un numero entre el 6 y el 9
```

Comment: No olvides darle el formato de _pregunta_ a tu pregunta... La respuesta está bien, pero no olvides el formato de [es.so].

Comment: ya, la gente me dio -1 super F jajaja yo que queria aportar y se fijaron en que la pregunta estaba mal formulada vaya error por parte mia. Queria  que llegase a mas gente

Comment: Me parece que aún se puede mejorar... El segundo párrafo suena a respuesta.

Comment: Ya le di una pulida :)

Comment: Voto por cerrar esta pregunta: porque  el formato de Q&A el OP solo copia de MDN el contenido: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math

Comment: Perfecto, muchas gracias ^^

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Intentare de manera mas coloquial o mas facil de entender explicar el proceso de lo que vamos a hacer.

Debemos conocer las funciones `Math.floor()` y `Math.random()`

`Math.floor()` devuelve el numero entero redondeado mas bajo, pongamos ejemplo

`Math.floor(2.95)` devolvera 2, mientras que `Math.floor(-2.95)` devolvera 3. Eso es porque -2.95 si lo redondeamos el entero MAS BAJO es -3 porque al ser negativo es mas bajo, sin embargo en 2.95 el mas bajo sigue siendo 2 ya que 3 al ser positivo es mas alto.

`Math.random()` devuelvo un numero entre 0 y 1, PERO CUIDADO el 1 no esta incluido. Aqui yo como ejemplo que me ayudo a entender, podemos pensar que el numero 1 tiene un "escudo" por delante que impide que random lo seleccione, por lo tanto dara numeros aleatorios como: 0.2, 0.3, 0.2324...etc. Es importante tenerlo claro para lo siguiente

Si queremos un numero aleatorio entre 0 y 9 haremos

```
const numRandom = Math.random() * 10;
//ponemos 10 para que incluya a 9 (le ponemos el escudo a 10)
//Imprimimos el numero en consola
console.log(numRandom); //nos sale con decimales
```

Para obtener un numero aleatorio entre 0 y 9 sin decimales anidaremos (meter una dentro de otra) las funciones. La primera funcion en colocar sera `Math.floor()` para que toda operacion que suceda dentro de ella se convierta a entero.

```
const numIntRandom = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
console.log(numIntRandom);
//obtendremos 10 numeros los cuales seran desde el 0 hasta el 9
```

Ahora se viene la operacion para hacer los rangos una vez entendido esto.
Para sacar un numero entre 1 y 5 usaremos un poco de algoritmia. No asustarse dividiremos el problema.

```
`Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);`
```

De primeras impresiona, pero vamos a ver que sucede y porque de forma sencilla.

Como el numero lo queremos entero, la funcion que engloba todo sera `Math.floor()`, hasta aqui bien, como en ejemplos anteriores. Para sacar un numero random usarmos `Math.random()`. Aqui DEBEMOS RECORDAR que lo que multiplique despues de esta funcion sera el limite o escudo donde nos chocaremos, es decir que si

```
const min = 1;
const max = 5;
`Math.floor(Math.random() * (5 - 1 + 1) + 1);`
```

El limite donde nos chocaremos sera la resta de 5 - 1 + 1 = 5. Si, en este ejemplo no tiene sentido restar el min - max para luego sumarle 1. Pero en otros ejemplos donde min no es 1, si veremos el cambio. Continuemos

Ya hemos divido y queda asi por el momento `Math.random() * 5 + 1`
La regla de las matematicas basica dice que las multiplicaciones predominan sobre las sumas y restas asi que esto nos dara como resultado un numero aleatorio al cual le sumaremos 1!!! Porqué sumarle 1?? porque

```
`Math.random() * 5 //dara como resultado un numero entre 0 y 5
```

No queremos eso queremos que sea entre 1 y 5, por eso al sumarle el min que queremos que es 1 al numero aleatorio generado, el entero mas pequeño que nos sacara sera 1 ya que le hemos sumado 1.
Lo que podia haber sido un numero entre 0 y 5 sera como minimo un numero entre 1 y 5, el numero que generamos lleva sumado un 1 siempre, por lo cual es imposible que nos de menos de eso.

Ahora vamos a dejar ya claro con el siguiente ejemploe explicado esta operacion, ya que todo ese parentesis de `max - min + 1` parecia que sobraba. PERO NO

Sacaremos el numero entre 6 y 9, entonces como hicimos antes plasmado en codigo quedaria:

```
const min = 6;
const max = 9;
Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
//JavaScript lo entenderia asi
//Math.floor(Math.random() * (9 - 6 + 1) + 6);
```

Bien aqui empieza la magia que hay en ese parentesis, `9 - 6 + 1 = 4` !!!Obtuvimos 4? Hay que recordar que `Math.random()` el numero que le multipliquemos actuara como un escudo o limite. Asi que ya sabemos que el numero aleatorio sera entre 0 y 3. Ahora a ese numero aleatorio le sumaremos 6 y obtendremos como explicamos en el ejemplo anterior, que el numero como minimo sera siempre 6.

Si el aleatorio que sera entre 0 y 3, nos sale el numero mas alto que es 3, este se lo sumaremos a 6 y nos dara 9!!!, 9 sera el maximo valor que obtendremos y 6 el minimo.
Asi es como funciona esta operacion. Dejare resuelta en un snippet como queda la funcion que valdria para cualquier rango de numeros.
He querido explanarme bien para que no se tienda a copiar y pegar sin entender que esta pasando ahi adentro y el porque del orden.

```js
function randomRangeNumber(min, max){
       return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
  }

console.log(randomRangeNumber(1, 5)) // debe devolver un numero entre el 1 y el 5
console.log(randomRangeNumber(6, 9)) // debe devolver un numero entre el 6 y el 9
```

Comment: Cabe decir, sin menostener la completa explicación que acabas de dar, que la misma función se encuentra como [ejemplo en la web de MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math#returning_a_random_integer_between_two_bounds)

Comment: Ya jajaj, a ver la funcion es siempre la misma por eso esta, con eso sacaras siempre el aleatorio entre un numero a y z. Pero a veces las terminologias o enunciados cuesta entenderlos como me paso y queria dejarlo super bien explicado para captarlo

Comment: no veo merito en transcribir una explicacion de MDN (manual) a este sitio... no somos una replica del manual: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math a menos que uses otros metodos para explicar lo que acabas de copiar y pegar ... no le veo sentido ... es lo mismo que mandar a alquien a leer la documentacion mediante un link en un comentario que tal vez haya se mantanga actualizado ... si algo cambiace esta respuesta quedaria inutil...

Comment: Pues el manual te deja la funcion y un poco de texto y la has de entender o copiar. Queria dejar claro y dividir las fases de toda esa linea de codigo para que se entienda bien a la primera. Vas al manual pero si por x razones no ves suficiente explicacion o por tenerla hecha la copias y te la llevas pues no se aprende de verdad el funcionamiento de toda esa linea. Basicamente he masticado su funcionamiento para que lo entienda todo el mundo

Answer (score 3):

## Uso de `Math.random()`

Usar [`Math.random()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random) es la manera fácil, simple y menos costosa de lograr el cometido. Por ejemplo, tal como se puede leer en la documentación y en la explicación de la misma, en la [respuesta de @FranyxD](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/560867/obtener-un-n%c3%bamero-aleatorio-dentro-de-un-rango-con-javascript/560868#560868); la siguiente función devuelve un número entero aleatorio entre los valores también enteros `a` y `b` dados (`b` no incluido):

```js
function getRandomIntegerNumberInRange(a, b) {
  if(a > b) {
    [a, b] = [b, a];
  }
  const amplitud = parseInt(b - a);
  const desplazamiento = parseInt(a);
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * amplitud) + desplazamiento;
}

console.log(getRandomIntegerNumberInRange(0, 30));
console.log(getRandomIntegerNumberInRange(0, -5));
console.log(getRandomIntegerNumberInRange(0, 2));
console.log(getRandomIntegerNumberInRange(-10, 5));
console.log(getRandomIntegerNumberInRange(-50, -1));
console.log(getRandomIntegerNumberInRange(0, 0));
console.log(getRandomIntegerNumberInRange(100, 100));
console.log(getRandomIntegerNumberInRange(10, 11));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  min-height: 100;
  top: 0;
}
```

Si los valores del rango se reciben en cualquier posición, esto se corrige dentro de la función por lo cual llamar a `getRandomIntegerNumberInRange(5, 0);` es igual que llamar a `getRandomIntegerNumberInRange(0, 5);`.

Por otro lado, la conversión del rango `[0, 1)` en el rango `[a, b)` para cualquier entero `a` y `b` es simplemente la multiplicación del rango inicial (`[0, 1)`) por la amplitud del rango objetivo (`b - a`) más su desplazamiento (dado por `a`).

Sin embargo, podemos crear nuestra propia función de números aleatorios sin necesidad de usar `Math.random()`.

## Uso de Generador de Números Pseudo Aleatorios

Podemos crear una Clase que implemente nuestro propio generador de números pseudo aleatorios como la siguiente, que explicaré a continuación:

```js
class CustomRandomGenerator {
  constructor(seed) {
    this.seed = seed ?? new Date().valueOf();
    this.mult = 1103515245;
    this.inc = 12345;
    this.mod = 2^31
  }
  
  *generate() {
    this.seed = (this.mult * this.seed + this.inc) % this.mod;
    yield (this.seed / this.mod);
  }
  
  rand() {
    return this.generate().next().value;
  }
}

const random = new CustomRandomGenerator();

function getRandomIntegerNumberInRange(a, b) {
  if(a > b) {
    [a, b] = [b, a];
  }
  const amplitud = parseInt(b - a);
  const desplazamiento = parseInt(a);
  return Math.floor(random.rand() * amplitud) + desplazamiento;
}

console.log(getRandomIntegerNumberInRange(0, 30));
console.log(getRandomIntegerNumberInRange(0, -5));
console.log(getRandomIntegerNumberInRange(0, 2));
console.log(getRandomIntegerNumberInRange(-10, 5));
console.log(getRandomIntegerNumberInRange(-50, -1));
console.log(getRandomIntegerNumberInRange(0, 0));
console.log(getRandomIntegerNumberInRange(100, 100));
console.log(getRandomIntegerNumberInRange(10, 11));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
```

## tl;dr

La mayoría de lenguajes de programación disponen de alguna función o método para calcular números pseudo aleatorios. En [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) tenemos el ya visto `Math.random()`, y en [java](/questions/tagged/java) tenemos disponible la Clase [Random](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html), la cual nos permite crear un objeto generador de números pseudo aleatorios de cualquier índole.

La mayoría de estos generadores se basan en un algortitmo para la obtención de dichos valores pseudo aleatorios, y dichos algoritmos no son un secreto, cualquiera puede recrearlos en el lenguaje que considere adecuado. Dado que la pregunta es sobre [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript), vamos a ver cómo se escribe una función generadora de números pseudo aleatorios sin necesidad de recurrir a `Math.random()`.

**Algoritmo**

Existen diferentes algoritmos de generación de números pseudo aleatorios, y aunque es un tema apasionante el estudio de algoritmos y sus diferentes aplicaciones, aquí sólo mostraremos un algoritmo bastante sencillo que podemos aplicar en [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) para la generación de dichos valores.

El proceso es muy simple:

1. Elección de un valor inicial conocido como "semilla"
2. Aplicación de una serie de operaciones matemáticas usando dicha "semilla" para obtener un valor pseudo aleatorio
3. Usar el valor obtenido como nueva "semilla"
4. Repetir el proceso para obtener el siguiente valor pseudo aleatorio.

El apartado 2 es el que miraremos con mayor atención, ya que es el que se encarga de calcular el resultado a partir de la entrada inicial.

**Principio matemático**

El algoritmo que usaremos es conocido como [Generador lineal congruencial](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generador_lineal_congruencial) y establece lo siguiente:

Dados un valor inicial `X_0` ("semilla"), dos valores `a` (multiplicador) y `c` (incremento) y un valor `m` (módulo), todos enteros positivos. Donde se cumple que:

- `m > 0` el módulo es siempre positivo, tal como se estableció anteriormente.
- `0 < a < m` el multiplicador es positivo pero menor que el módulo.
- `0 ≤ c < m` el incremento es no negativo, pero siempre menor que el módulo
- `0 ≤ X_0 < m` la semilla es no negativa y menor que el módulo

Se establece la relación lineal de *congruencia* de la siguiente forma:

```
Xn ≡ (aXn-1 + c) mod m
```

O traducido a [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript):

```
Xn = (a * Xn-1 + c) % m;
```

Esto es algo que podemos escribir sin problemas en una función que, dados los valores inciales y un valor `n`, nos devolverá una lista de `n` elementos generados de forma pseudo aleatoria:

```js
// seed: semilla, mult: multiplicador, inc: incremento, mod: modulo, n: cantidad de elementos
function linearPseudoRandomGeneratorList(seed, mult, inc, mod, n) {
  const list = [];
  for( let i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    seed = ((mult * seed) + inc) % mod;
    list.push(seed);
  }
  return list;
}

console.log(linearPseudoRandomGeneratorList(10, 1, 3, 50, 10).join(','));
console.log(linearPseudoRandomGeneratorList(10, 1, 3, 50, 10).join(','));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
```

Ahora, esta función nos devuelve una lista que es predecible, es decir son valores que tienen una frecuencia predecible según se conozcan los componentes que son introducidos. Para los mismos valores siempre de obtendrán los mismos resultados. Esto no es aleatoreidad tal como la conocemos.

¿Cómo podríamos aleatorizar aún más nuestro resultado? Pues podemos usar valores "aleatorios" para el multiplicador, el incremento y la semilla, de esta forma los valores generados serían menos predecibles.

Como en nuestro ejemplo no podemos usar `Math.random()` entonces usaremos la hora del sistema para obtener el valor de semilla inicial y así obtener diferentes resultados en cada llamada a nuestro generador.

Recordemos los requisitos: todos enteros positivos menores que `m`. Como [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) trabaja con una representación numérica de 64 bits, podemos usar como módulo un valor tan alto como se desee siempre que no sea más alto que el [máximo entero seguro](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER) que es de magnitud: `2^53 - 1` y equivale a: `9007199254740991`. Pero en este caso, vamos a escoger valores o parámetros estándar usados en muchos generadores a día de hoy. Por ejemplo, podemos basarnos en los valores para `m`, `a` y `c` propuestos como [parámetros de uso común](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generador_lineal_congruencial#Par%C3%A1metros_de_uso_com%C3%BAn) de cualquier lenguaje o implementación. Supongamos que tomamos los parámetros usados comunmente en `ANSI C`:

- `m`: 2^31
- `a`: 1103515245
- `c`: 12345

Para la semilla, usaremos el valor devuelto por el método [`valueOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/valueOf) del objeto `Date`de [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript).

Por ejemplo:

```js
function linearPseudoRandomGeneratorList(n) {
  let seed = new Date().valueOf();
  const mod = 2^31;
  const mult = 1103515245;
  const inc = 12345;
  const list = [];
  for( let i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    seed = ((mult * seed) + inc) % mod;
    list.push(seed / mod);
  }
  return list;
}


console.log(linearPseudoRandomGeneratorList(5).join(','));
// el siguiente bucle sólo es para evitar que la siguiente
// llamada sea en el mismo instante de tiempo
for(let i = 1; i < 10000; ++i) {
  i;
}
console.log(linearPseudoRandomGeneratorList(5).join(','));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
```

Como se aprecia, si bien la única entrada es la cantidad de elementos a generar, los valores generados en ambas llamadas parecen más aleatorios y son distintos en cada llamada, por lo cual, algo se ha ganado.

Otra cosa que hemos cambiado es que nuestro resultado tenga una [Distribución Uniforme](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribuci%C3%B3n_uniforme_continua). Esto lo logramos dividiendo el valor obtenido, entre el módulo. Así, los valores obtenidos estarán siempre entre `[0, 1)`.

Ya nos hemos acercado bastante a lo que proporciona `Math.random()`.

**Generador**

Ahora bien, ¿cómo podemos escribir una función que dados 2 valores cualesquiera `a` y `b` nos devuelva un valor aleatorio en el rango `[a, b)` usando nuestro generador?

Pues lo primero es crear una [función generadora](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*) que nos permita obtener un valor aleatorio en cada llamada a `next()`. Para ello vamos a hacer lo siguiente:

```js
class CustomRandomGenerator {
  constructor(seed) {
    this.seed = seed ?? new Date().valueOf();
    this.mult = 1103515245;
    this.inc = 12345;
    this.mod = 2^31
  }
  
  *generate() {
    this.seed = (this.mult * this.seed + this.inc) % this.mod;
    yield (this.seed / this.mod);
  }
  
  rand() {
    return this.generate().next().value;
  }
}

const random = new CustomRandomGenerator();

console.log(random.rand());
console.log(random.rand());
console.log(random.rand());
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
```

Con esto hemos creado una Clase llamada `CustomRandomGenerator` que puede recibir un valor como semilla o usar la hora del sistema. Esta Clase implementa una función generadora que devolverá un valor pseudo aleatorio entre 0 y 1, basado en la semilla inicial, y una función llamada `rand()` que consume nuestra función generadora para devolvernos el siguiente valor pseudo aleatorio.

Ahora, es fácil construir una función que devuelva un valor pseudo aleatorio en un rango específico dado, tal como la primera función vista al inicio de esta respuesta. Por ejemplo:

```js
class CustomRandomGenerator {
  constructor(seed) {
    this.seed = seed ?? new Date().valueOf();
    this.mult = 1103515245;
    this.inc = 12345;
    this.mod = 2^31
  }
  
  *generate() {
    this.seed = (this.mult * this.seed + this.inc) % this.mod;
    yield (this.seed / this.mod);
  }
  
  rand() {
    return this.generate().next().value;
  }
}

const random = new CustomRandomGenerator();

function getRandomIntegerNumberInRange(a, b) {
  if(a > b) {
    [a, b] = [b, a];
  }
  const amplitud = parseInt(b - a);
  const desplazamiento = parseInt(a);
  return Math.floor(random.rand() * amplitud) + desplazamiento;
}

console.log(getRandomIntegerNumberInRange(0, 30));
console.log(getRandomIntegerNumberInRange(0, -5));
console.log(getRandomIntegerNumberInRange(0, 2));
console.log(getRandomIntegerNumberInRange(-10, 5));
console.log(getRandomIntegerNumberInRange(-50, -1));
console.log(getRandomIntegerNumberInRange(0, 0));
console.log(getRandomIntegerNumberInRange(100, 100));
console.log(getRandomIntegerNumberInRange(10, 11));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
```

Como se observa, no es tan difícil obtener los valores pseudo aleatorios usando el algoritmo apropiado. Sin embargo, no siempre es bueno reinventar la rueda. Esta respuesta intenta ser más didáctica que otra cosa.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que a lo mejor necesitas es esta función:

```
function randomRangeNumber(Minimo,Maximo){
    var posibilidades = Maximo - Minimo;
    var a = Math.random() * posibilidades;
    a = Math.floor(a);
    return parseInt(Minimo) + a;
} 

console.log(randomRangeNumber(1, 5)) // debe devolver un numero entre el 1 y el 5
console.log(randomRangeNumber(6, 9)) // debe devolver un numero entre el 6 y el 9
```